# IBM WORKLIGHT 6.1 - Analytics data was not processed due to an exception

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

I have installed Worklight Server 6.1 over Libery Profile, the database i am using is MySql. I have imported the required databases wrklght and wlreports. I am trying to deploy authentication project, i have changed the DB settings in worklight.properties file and i added wl.db.factProcessingInterval=100 in order to generate the report for each minute. But when i am running the app, it shows

```
Table 'wrklght.proc_report' doesn't exist {prepstmnt 250489235 SELECT MAX(t0.PROC_TIMESTAMP) FROM PROC_REPORT t0} [code=1146, state=42S02]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0182E: Notification analytics data was not processed due to an exception [project AdapterBasedAuth]
Table 'wrklght.notification_proc_report' doesn't exist {prepstmnt 1989504497 SELECT MAX(t0.PROC_TIMESTAMP) FROM NOTIFICATION_PROC_REPORT t0} [code=1146, state=42S02]
```

But the proc_report and notification_proc_report tables are available in the wrklght databse.

Comment: The message says that there are no wrklght.proc_report, and wrklght.notification_proc_report tables. Are you sure you are connecting to the correct DB and tables are there? Try to use other JDBC client (e.g. Squirrel) with the same user and check, if you have access to these tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that those tables do not exist or are not configured correctly. Can you please verify you have configured your MySql databases by following the instructions below:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_setting_up_your_my_sql_database_manually.html?resultof=%22%57%4c%52%45%50%4f%52%54%22%20%22%77%6c%72%65%70%6f%72%74%22%20

After the configuration and setup has been completed can you tell us if the error persists

Comment: As you stated in the answer, i have created the database simply create database wrklght; once i provided the privilege to the db and gave the url to access..It can successfully reach the db.